# change input/select to hidden field if only 1 record

Tags: php, cakephp

How do i change select to hidden field if it has only 1 record. If only 1 branch i want it to be hidden with that id, as the branch_id, being the value.

**View**

```
    echo $this->Form->input('branch_id');
```

**CTRL**

```
    $this->set('branches', $this->Holiday->Branch->find('list'));
```

Comment: i think you need to post more code, how do we know what these other branches are?  Hard to know how you would count them to determine if it's more than one.

Comment: so does this `$this->Holiday->Branch->find('list')` return an array?  If so, use sizeof and then do something different if it's > 1.  There still isn't much info....remember we don't know what these variables are from your question

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, assuming it returns an array:

```
if(count($branches) == 1) {
    echo $this->Form->input('branch_id', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $branches['Branch'][0]['branch_id']));
}
```